# Find element in hierarchy

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, common-table-expression, hierarchical

I'm trying to create a hierarchical query using `WITH` of T-SQL. What I want to do is, for example, to find if John is a boss of Ryan, directly or indirectly?

How can I write a query for this?

Comment: Read up on common table expressions (often shortened to "CTE"). Once you've got to grips with those, read up on recursive CTEs :-)

Comment: Post more detatils, your table, what result you want, and what you tried...

Answer (score 2):

```
WITH BossOf AS(
   SELECT bossId, Id From Employees
       UNION ALL
   SELECT b.bossId, e.Id 
   FROM Employees AS e
   INNER JOIN BossOf b ON b.Id = e.bossId
)
SELECT * FROM BossOf
   WHERE Id = 'Ryan'
```

Just as an example of what you can do with BossOf...

```
WITH BossOf AS(
   SELECT bossId, Id From Employees
       UNION ALL
   SELECT b.bossId, e.Id 
   FROM Employees AS e
   INNER JOIN BossOf b ON b.Id = e.bossId
)
SELECT * FROM Employees
    WHERE Id IN (SELECT BossId 
                    FROM BossOf
                    Where Id = 'Ryan')
```

Or Even

```
WITH BossOf AS(
   SELECT bossId, Id From Employees
       UNION ALL
   SELECT b.bossId, e.Id 
   FROM Employees AS e
   INNER JOIN BossOf b ON b.Id = e.bossId
)
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM BossOf
   WHERE Id = 'Ryan'
   AND BossId = 'John'
```

Comment: However, this query return the whole hierarchy for the org.  How can I limit the tree to only Ryan's bosses??

Comment: Just think of BossOf as a SQL View that gets thrown away after the next query.

Comment: Be aware that you may need an explicit semi colon before this code.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Aron!!  However, this is what I wanted to avoid.  The actual data hierarchy for my company is very big, and retrieve the whole tree first and then find if A is child of B looks very expensive. ??

Comment: Actually, try the query out. SQL server's query planner will actually make it much more efficient than you would expect. The temporary view (CTE) isn't ever materialised. Also since it is inline, the query planner will rearrange the query and put the WHERE Id = 'Ryan' right in the deepest nesting.

It is actually deceptively cheap to run this query.